# Extending JMeter or write complex scenario?

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I have several thousands of files, some of them contain HTTP request and some of them contain corresponding HTTP response. I want to create some script, which spawns hundreds/thousands of threads and each thread should take HTTP request, send it to the server and compare response from server with corresponding response file.

I'm not sure if I have to create custom sampler with configuration, or I can use existing pieces of JMeter functions to create one?

Also I was not able to find reliable documentation of how to extend JMeter with new Samplers. This one seems to be outdated: http://www.jajakarta.org/jmeter/1.7/en/extending/JMeter%20Extension%20Scenario.html

May be somebody could advice where I can find latest guide, covering creation of Samplers? For example, how to create Sampler which will take a directory as argument and iterate over every file in that directory, then make request/compare response and tell JMeter if that one was correctly processed by WEB server along with timings?

Comment: As well check new Jmeter 2.7 for new features and samplers: http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should just use regulat JMeter scenario. Implement list of files with CSV Data Set, spawn some threads with this set with Thread Group. Each thread gets the name of the request/response files pair from CSV Data Set, uses HTTP/TCP sampler to send request and an Assertion (Response Assertion) to verify response.

MD5 assertion can be even faster way to check the response.

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple. Load testing is hard enough without making the test complicated.